# OBIEE 12C authorization failed based on database view

Tags: oracle, authentication, authorization, weblogic12c, obiee

In our environment (OBIEE 12C installed on Linux) we use an external authentication provider based on a view in our database. After logging in, authorization happens via a session variable initialised in an initialisation block in the RPD with a query based on the same view as for authentication.

What happened a few days ago is that people could log in (so the password saved in the view was being checked correctly) but authentication failed and they got the value of our default provided in the initialisation block.

Looking at the logs we found this error:
**[nQSError: 17001] Oracle Error code: 3135, message: ORA-03135: connection lost contact**
and 
**Query for Initialization Block 'AUTHORISATION' has failed**.

Looking in the logs for authorization, nothing bad was found here but we can't seem to figure out how authentication worked and authorization didn't since they are based on the same database view. Has anyone ever had this issue before?

We've faced this issue multiple times but found that some users had the right authorization and authentication in between the errors.

Any help would be great, also where I can look further to troubleshoot this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're having connectivity issues with the DB and the init block can't run. Nothing to do with OBI or the query - that's rather network, connectivity, firewall etc etc